# Where does this quote/poem come from?

Tags: references, quotation

Some time ago I came across (somewhere in the wide, wide net) this statistics limerick, which I liked very much:

> User beware, one must take so much care
>   in matters statistical, be right and aware
>   lest LODs lose their meaning
>   and false positives be teeming
>   though nothing worth noting is there!

However, I lost the note where it came from, and I cannot find the original source.

Have you seen it? Know where it came from? Maybe even know a proper reference I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling the third line of this poem leads to exactly two hits: one is this question and another is a page that provides an answer: [watson.hgen.pitt.edu/humor/Unpublishable_Humor.html](http://watson.hgen.pitt.edu/humor/Unpublishable_Humor.html). Let me quote it directly:

> **Unpublishable Humor**
>
> *by Amrita Ray & Daniel E. Weeks*
>
> Our very fine limerick was judged unpublishable by the American Journal of Human Genetics: [...]. Our limerick was to appear as the conclusion at the end of our Letter to the Editor:
>
> [Ray A, Weeks DE. No convincing evidence of linkage for restless legs syndrome on chromosome 9p. Am J Hum Genet. 2005 Apr;76(4):705-7; author reply 707-10. PMID: 15747259](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1199308/)
>
> But, unfortunately, the Editor requested that we remove our limerick: [...]
>
> Acknowledgment: We thank our colleagues in our Fall 2004 Quantitative Genetics class for helping us improve the wording of our limerick.

Let me only add that "LOD" probably refers to the [logarithm-of-odds score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_linkage#LOD_score_method_for_estimating_recombination_frequency) in genetic linkage analysis.

Comment: Thanks a lot, including the direct quote: not only can links rot "tweaking" the search can be even more difficult particularly if google tries to be helpful...

Comment: Also thanks for explaining LOD in the genetics context. In my field (chemometrics) LOD is the limit of detection, for which the warning is also valid.